# How can I make sure that terminal searches the venv folder and not the default python location for third party modules?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, virtual-environment

Although I have implemented Virtual Environment inside a project in PyCharm IDE, when I trigger `python -m behave` it says:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

How can I make sure that terminal searches the `venv` folder and not the default python location?

I made sure that inside *settings>tools>Terminal*, "Activate Virtual Environment" is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal in PyCharm is still just a system terminal.

So you should add your python binarys path to your systems PATH environment variable.

Or you can use the option "Environment Variables" inside *settings/tools/Terminal* and add a new entry there like *PATH=$PATH$;< Path to your python binary >*

Then python should launch in PyCharms terminal window.

But to access your virtual environment you still need to start it like in a normal terminal: *venv\Scripts\activate* (on Windows).

Comment: Thanks @tenigas for the response. But after activating the Virtual Environment, its still throwing me an error. It is still searching in the AppData folder(default python libraries path) and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I had to delete the venv folder and create a new Virtual environment. But following what you said, worked this time. Thanks again.